# cellular network: circuit- or packet-switched?

Tags: cellular-network

Are the cell phone networks circuit- or packet-switched networks? Why?
I belive both of them but I'm not sure. I can't find an answer to my question on the net.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is both.

Traditionally, when a voice call is placed it goes over a circuit-switched network. However, in the last few years, VoLTE (Voice over LTE) has been rolling out, enabling voice calls to take place over a packet-switched network.

There is plenty of information about this on the web.

Answer (score 1):

LTE ("4G") is a packet-switch only network for both data and voice. Older cellular networks (UMTS, HSDPA, HSUPA, GERAN) use circuit switch for voice calls.